# undefined reference in ESPHome custom component

Tags: c++, home-assistant, esphome

I'm trying to make a WiFi enabled egg-cooker. I have a working Arduino sketch and am now trying to port it to ESPHome so that it can interface with Home Assistant. Here's a link to the code: https://github.com/Amanoo/Smart-Egg-Cooker/tree/feature-esphome/eggslice

In this folder, run these commands:

```
python3 -m venv venv 
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install esphome
pip3 install tornado esptool
esphome run eggcooker.yaml
```

This will compile the whole thing. However, it will eventually throw an error:

```
/home/marco/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: .pioenvs/eggcooker/src/main.cpp.o:(.literal._ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFSt6vectorIPN7esphome9ComponentESaIS3_EEvEZ5setupvEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data+0x8): undefined reference to `EggCooker::EggCooker(esphome::sensor::Sensor*, esphome::text_sensor::TextSensor*)'
/home/marco/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: .pioenvs/eggcooker/src/main.cpp.o: in function `std::_Function_handler<std::vector<esphome::Component*, std::allocator<esphome::Component*> > (), setup()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&)':
/home/marco/Desktop/Smart-Egg-Cooker-feature-esphome/eggslice/.esphome/build/eggcooker/eggcooker.yaml:53: undefined reference to `EggCooker::EggCooker(esphome::sensor::Sensor*, esphome::text_sensor::TextSensor*)'
```

In my yaml file, my custom component is defined as follows:

```
custom_component:
    - lambda: |-
        auto my_custom = new EggCooker(id(secs),id(state));
        App.register_component(my_custom);
        return {my_custom};
```

This should create the entire thing. Secs is a sensor with device_class duration, and state is a text_sensor, both described in the yaml. These are passed to the EggCooker constructor. The EggCooker is defined in the eggslice.h file and accompanying cpp.

`EggCooker::EggCooker(Sensor* secs, TextSensor* state)  : secs_(secs), state_(state) {}`
should just use the two sensors and save their pointers. Seems like it's the type of constructor the yaml should want. Yet, it complains.

I've tried to include my C++ code in the yaml, which should be obvious. Wrote a constructor for an object that is expected by the yaml code. Still throwqs an error. I've tried to toy around with namespaces and with adding `esphome::sensor::` and `esphome::text_sensor::` in front of everywhere, but it just won't stop complaining about this. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add SOLVED to the title, or to edit a solution into the answer. You've written an answer, which you can accept to let people know you've solved the problem. For more information about how the site works, see the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I needed to include the cpp file as well in my yaml, I only included the .h file. Still some errors but I think I'm making progress.